# “not all code path return a value” error occurs in a method, but I did use some if statements to cover all scenario

Tags: c#, if-statement, compiler-errors, return

This may be a stupid question, but I just want to somebody can give a better explanation.

I have a method defined as below:

```
    private int Test(int i)
    {
        if (i < 0) return -1;
        if (i == 0) return 0;
        if (i > 0) return 1;

        //return 0;        
    }
```

It gives me this error "not all code path return a value".

I thought I had 3 `if statement`, which could cover all the scenarios(i<0, i==0, i>0). So it should not show me this error.

Comment: By the way, you could replace this method with [`Math.Sign(i)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sign?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Yes, the compiler is not smart enough to get that in case of `int i` all scenarios are covered; as an excuse of the false alert, please, note that for `double i` the warning is *correct* (`double.NaN` will pass *all three* `if`s)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, thank you, and also let me know another scenario `double.NaN`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler just ain't that clever. Also, you're code is slightly inefficient in that it tests for a certainty (`i` must be greater than zero in the last case).

Write it as:

```
private int Test(int i)
{
    if (i < 0) return -1;
    else if (i == 0) return 0;
    else return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

During compile-time, the compiler doesn't analyze the conditions and understands that they cover all the options - it just sees three unrelated `if` statements, and a path with no `return` if none of them are triggered.

You can make it "understand" by using `else if` and `else`s:

```
private int Test(int i)
{
    if (i < 0) return -1;
    else if (i == 0) return 0;
    else return 1;        
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep your format, a way to do it is like this...

```
private int Test(int i)
{
   bool result = 1;

   if (i < 0) result = -1;
   if (i == 0) result = 0;
   if (i > 1) result = 1; //This is redundant because i is initialized to 1

   return result;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't allow this code past a code review. It is inefficient and difficult to read.

Comment: @JasperKent Maybe in this case is a bit inefficient (after all it can be done in one line) but I do not believe it is difficult to read. I think there are cases that this may come handy...