# Not all code paths return a value when comparing 2 dates?

Tags: c#, class, date

I've been messing around with this for a long time and I couldn't find out what code path doesn't return a value. I'm trying to check if an entered date is later than the current date. I'd thank you if you can help me out with this problem. (Date is a class and the brackets are me testing it out with an example.)

```
public bool IsLater(Date d)
{                              //Date d = 2020/4/25  Date = 2020/4/21
    if (d.year > year) //false
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (d.year < year) //false
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (d.year == year)//true
    {
        if (d.month > month)//false
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (d.month < month)//false
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (d.month == month)//true
        {
            if (d.day > day)//true
            {
                return true;//ok
            }
            if (d.day < day)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if (d.day == day)
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What datatypes are your year, month and day fields/properties? If they are nullable, then the paths do not hit. A solution is to remove the check for equal year and month, since before that, you check for less-than and greater-than. So those is-equal-to if's are redundant.

Comment: why not `return d.Date > new DateTime(year, month, day);`?

Comment: This has been answered in a question that just [came up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61135896/not-all-code-path-return-a-value-error-occurs-in-a-method-but-i-did-use-some)

Comment: @Maarten right, my bad, i'm just a beginner so I make some rookie mistakes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can let .Net make the work for you: why reinvent the wheel? Comparing dates is just `>` operator:

```
// Later: d is more than (year, month, day)
public bool IsLater(DateTime d) => d.Date > new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

If you insist on keeping your current routine, let compiler know that `if`s are *combined*: turn `if` into `else if` and final `if` in each group into `else`

```
public bool IsLater(Date d)
{                              
    if (d.year > year) 
        return true;
    else if (d.year < year) 
        return false;
    else // we have nothing else but equal years
    {
        if (d.month > month)
            return true;
        else if (d.month < month)
            return false;
        else // nothing else but equal months
        {
            if (d.day > day)
                return true;
            else if (d.day < day)
                return false;
            else 
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would rewrite it to this. IMHO easier to read, and no 'not all paths ...' warning.

```
return
    d.year > year ||
    (d.year == year && d.month > month) ||
    (d.year == year && d.month == month && d.day > day)
    ;
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain in a couple words what every step does? appreciate your time

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `DateTime` class instead:

```
public bool IsLater(Date d)
{   
    DateTime a = new DateTimte (year, month, day);
    DateTime b = new DateTimte (d.year, d.month, d.day);
    return b > a;
}
```